# How do I determine week ranges with PHP?

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to determine the week ranges from Monday - Sunday with PHP.  I'm able to calculate the week number but I can't ssem to get the correct ending week range for each week.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$start_date = 1337621424;
$end_date = 1349964545;

$start_week = (int)date('W', $start_date); 
$end_week = (int)date('W', $end_date); 

echo "START WEEK: " . $start_week . "<BR>";
echo "END WEEK: " . $end_week . "<BR>";

$dates = array();

if ($start_week && $end_week) {

    for ($week=$start_week; $week<=$end_week; $week++) {
        echo "WEEK: " . $week . "<BR>";

        $startdate = strtotime ( '- ' . $week. ' week', strtotime ( date('Y-m-d') ) ) ;
        $startdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $startdate );

        //$end = date('Y-m-d');
        $end = strtotime ( '- ' . ($week + 1) . ' week', strtotime ( $startdate ) ) ;
        $end = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $end );

        $dates[$week]['start'] = $startdate;
        $dates[$week]['end'] = $end;
    }

    print_r($dates);
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing or is there an easier way?

Comment: You are manipulating `($week + 1) weeks` from startdate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$startDate = new DateTime();
$startDate->setTimestamp(1337621424);

$endDate = new DateTime();
$endDate->setTimestamp(1349964545);

$dates = array();
while ( $startDate <= $endDate ) {
    $week = array();
    $week['start'] = $startDate->format("Y-m-d");
    $startDate->modify("+1 week");
    $week['end'] = $startDate->format("Y-m-d");

    $dates[$startDate->format("W")] = $week ;
}
var_dump($dates);
```